# wagtail-modeltranslation Model already contain field

Tags: python, django, wagtail, django-cms, django-modeltranslation

thank you for reading my post.

actually my problem is that when migrating from: (wagtail==1.9.1 ; wagtail_modeltranslation==0.6.0rc2) to (wagtail==2.8 ; wagtail-modeltranslation==0.10.17)

I get the following error:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail_modeltranslation/apps.py", line 31, in ready
    handle_translation_registrations()
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/models.py", line 75, in handle_translation_registrations
    autodiscover()
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/models.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/myproject/myproject/home/translation.py", line 26, in <module>
    class HomePageTranslation(BaseTranslationOptions):
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/decorators.py", line 23, in wrapper
    translator.register(model_or_iterable, opts_class, **options)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/translator.py", line 457, in register
    self._register_single_model(model, opts)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/translator.py", line 474, in _register_single_model
    add_translation_fields(model, opts)
  File "/home/taha/Desktop/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/translator.py", line 163, in add_translation_fields
    (model._meta.object_name, localized_field_name))
ValueError: Error adding translation field. Model 'HomePage' already contains a field named 'search_description_de'.
```

Any help please?